Jetpack compose date picker
I'm looking for some advice on a Jetpack compose App I'm doing in Android Studio.
It is very simple but I'm very new to this.
All it does is a calculation on the current date to spit out a number (iPin). This works.
It also brings up a date picker so you can do the same calculation on a future or past date. The date picker works and displays the new data (m.Date.Value) via text on the main screen but I can not figure out how to get it to redo the calculation on the number (sPin).
I want sPin to update at the same time as mDate.value.
Thanks.
@Composable
public fun MyContent(
    imagePainter: Painter,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
){

    // Fetching the Local Context
    val mContext = LocalContext.current

    // Declaring integer values
    // for year, month and day
    val mYear: Int
    val mMonth: Int
    val mDay: Int

    // Initializing a Calendar
    val mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()

    // Fetching current year, month and day
    mYear = mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    mMonth = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    mDay = mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

    mCalendar.time = Date()

    var iPin = calcPin(mDay, mMonth, mYear)
    var sPin = 0

    // Declaring a string value to
    // store date in string format
    val mDate = remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    // Declaring DatePickerDialog and setting
    // initial values as current values (present year, month and day)
    val mDatePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(
        mContext,
        { _: DatePicker, mYear: Int, mMonth: Int, mDayOfMonth: Int ->
            mDate.value = "$mDayOfMonth/${mMonth+1}/$mYear"
            calcPin(mDay, mMonth, mYear).also { sPin = it }
        }, mYear, mMonth, mDay
    )

    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center, horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {

        Image(
            painter = imagePainter,
            contentDescription = null,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(alignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
                .size(250.dp)
        )
        // Displaying the mDate value in the Text
        Text(text = "Todays Number: ${iPin}", fontSize = 30.sp, textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
        // Adding a space of 100dp height
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp))

        // Creating a button that on
        // click displays/shows the DatePickerDialog
        Button(onClick = {
            mDatePickerDialog.show()
             }, colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color(0XFF0F9D58)) ) {
            Text(text = "Select Date", color = Color.White)
        }

        // Adding a space of 50dp height
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(50.dp))

        // Displaying the mDate value in the Text
        Text(text = "Selected Date: ${mDate.value}", fontSize = 30.sp, textAlign = TextAlign.Center)

        Text(text = "Selected Number: ${sPin}", fontSize = 30.sp, textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
        // Adding a space of 100dp height
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp))
    }
}

fun calcPin(d: Int, m: Int, y: Int): Int {
    var iResult: Int

    iResult = d + m+ y

    return iResult
}

I can not figure out how to get it to redo the calculation (sPin) when the date is selected.
I want sPin to update at the same time as mDate.value.
I have tried moving the call to the calcPin Function after val mDatePickerDialog I have also moved it to just before Text(text = "Selected Number: ${sPin}",  but no luck.

For the calculation of sPin you use calcPin(mDay, mMonth, mYear). I think you want to use mDayOfMonth instead of mDay, though.

Hi Leviathan. Thank you you are correct I should have been using mDayOfMonth so with your sugestion and Vishnu fix I got it working. Thank you.

this issue can be fixed by making the varibale sPin a mutable state. Please find the code below.
var sPin by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

edit: why? currently, the issue is sPin being just a variable; converting that to a mutable state & wrapping that in a remember block makes the UI to recompose everytime the value of sPin changes.

You answer would be better if you explained why this solves the problem.

Hi Vishnu. Yes you are correct I did this and changed other relevant items and it worked.
Thank you very much.

@Leviathan done, sorry for the trouble. and, CMIIW. :)
